# Uploading and downloading the whole database from Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I just want to know if it is possible to download and upload the whole database from Google App Engine to a SQLite db, in case I want to transfer my app from Google App Engine to another server?

What is the chance?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a project called [approcket](http://code.google.com/p/approcket/) that synchronizes Google App Engine datastore and a local MySQL database. Maybe you should have a look.

Answer (score 0):

In [a related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894840/gae-datastore-backup/1895517#1895517), I linked to the documentation for the bulk loader tool.

However you will be more interested in the rest of the document, especially the section on [creating an exporter class](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata.html#Creating_Exporter_Classes) for exportation of the data.

Comment: Hi jhs,

I does not mean the bulkloader because it allows me to upload/download seperate instance only. I want a whole database at one time, is it possible? the task that I usually do in sql server management tools for sql server?

Comment: did you read the section of the linked document called "uploading and downloading all data? the bulkloader does grab all entities of a given kind at once.  If you want the entire database, just write a script that loops through all of your kinds.

Comment: in fact, I have written codes to grab all the entities of a kind. I just want to know if there exists a method easier to grab all the database at once. downloading the data will give us only the .csv file, not the backup of the database.