# GAE Datastore Backup using Java and Cron

Tags: java, cron, google-cloud-datastore

I want to backup (and later restore) data from GAE datastore using the export facilities that went [live this year](https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2018/02/fully-managed-export-and-import-with-Cloud-Datastore-now-generally-available.html).  I want to use cron and java.  I have found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894840/gae-datastore-backup) which points at [this page](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/schedule-export) but it's just for phython.

Originally I wanted to do this automatically every day using the Google Cloud Platform console but I can't find a way of doing it. Now I am resorting to incorporating it into Java and a cron job.  I need restore instructions as well as backup.

I'm not interested in using the datastore admin backup as this will no longer be available next year.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Datastore export logic in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53311984/datastore-export-logic-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

According to the docs, the way to do it is, indeed, through Cron for GAE and having a GAE module call the API to export.

The point is not the code itself, but understanding why this is so.

Currently, the easiest way to schedule tasks in GCP is though Cron jobs in GAE, but those can only call GAE modules. Following [the docs that you pointed out](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/schedule-export), the Cron will be quite similar to the one described there.

Regarding the handler itself, you only need to call the [Datastore Admin API](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/admin/rest/v1/projects/export) authenticated with an account with the proper permissions.

Since the [Cloud Client Library](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-java/google-cloud-clients/apidocs/com/google/cloud/datastore/package-summary.html) does not have admin capabilities for Datastore, you'll have to either construct the call manually, or use the [Datastore API Client Library](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/datastore/v1/java/latest/com/google/api/services/datastore/v1/model/GoogleDatastoreAdminV1ExportEntitiesRequest.html).

Notice that, for GCP APIs, there are usually [two client libraries available](https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/client-libraries-explained): the Cloud Client Library and the API Client Library. The first one is hand-crafted while the second one is auto-generated from the discovery document of each API.

If one specific functionality is not available through the Cloud Client Library (the recommended way of interacting with GCP APIs), you can always check the API Client Library for that same functionality.

Comment: Sorry Johre but the time this question took to become active made it irrelevant, thanks for the answer anyway